# Is there an alternative to Jspdf that support UTF-8?

Tags: javascript, html, printing, jspdf

I need to load an HTML table to pdf file and download it, I can do this using Jspdf, but it doesn't support UTF-8 and I can't include many languages like Arabic , i'm using laravel

Comment: @JamithNImantha That question doesn't have comments or answers, why would anyone look at it?